# Check if index exist

Tags: database-indexes, sql-server-2019

How do I check if an index already on SQL server if the index has 2 or more columns?
I don't want to check for name only I want to check by table by columns

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little vague, but if I understand correctly, you want to find indexes on all tables where the index has two or more columns:

```
select t.[name] TableName, i.[name] IndexName
from (
    select object_id, Index_Id
    from sys.index_columns
        group by object_Id, Index_Id
    having Count(*)>1
)x 
join sys.indexes i on i.index_id=x.index_id and i.object_id=x.object_id
join sys.tables t on t.object_id=x.object_id and t.[type]='U'
order by Tablename, IndexName
```

Comment: Clarify what else you need / different?

Comment: Not quite.    

I need to create an index on Table A for Columns 1 and 2    
CREATE INDEX Name on [Table_A] ([Column_1], [Column_2])


Is there away to check if there is another index on Table_A for Column_1 and Column_2 with another name?